# Appending the filename beginning of each line

Tags: java

I have to merge different files into one file according to the time stamp. I have succeeded in sorting them and bringing them to one single file. 
In order to know where the lines came from(from which file), i am trying to add the original filename beginning of each line.

```
For ex:
File1 :
12:23:21,234 some text
13:23:21,234 some text
17:45:12,576 some text

File2 :
15:23:21,234 some text
15:28:01,254 some text

Merged file :
File1 - 12:23:21,234 some text
File1 - 13:23:21,234 some text
File2 - 15:23:21,234 some text
File2 - 15:28:01,254 some text
File1 - 17:45:12,576 some text
```

I am trying to add that filename in the beginning of each line like mentioned above. Could anyone help me figure out how to append the file name?

Comment: when you read the line just simply make a new `String` where it will be something like this `newString = file.getName()+" - "+textFromFile;`

Comment: Can you post what your code looks like so far?  Think it should be straightforward from there.

Comment: while (checkLinesNotNull(firstLineObj)) {
    for(int i=0; i<firstLineObj.size();i++){
     notimelines(firstLineObj.get(i), bw);
    }if (checkLinesNotNull(firstLineObj)) {
        
         sort(firstLineObjs);        
       bw.write(firstLineObj.get(0).line);
          bw.newLine();
         }
    Data data = notimelines(firstLineObj.get(0),bw);
    if(data.isCompleted){
       firstLineObj.remove(firstLineObj.get(0));
      }
    }
   }

Answer (score 0):

Are you on some kind of Unix-like system? If so, and assuming filenames do not contain spaces and time stamps are easy to sort:

```
grep -H . File* | perl -pe 's/:/ - /;' | sort -k3
```

Comment: No. It is a Java Standalone Project i am developing.