# Append Filename at the beginning of each text file in a given folder

Tags: batch-file, command-line

So I have a folder with hundreds of OCR output text files. I'm trying to make a batch file which will append the filename at the beginning of every file.

So far, I looked thru and found this code on stackoverflow, but it appends the filename at the beginning of each line. 
[Appending the filename beginning of each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222442/appending-the-filename-beginning-of-each-line)

```
    @echo off
if "%~1" equ ":FindFiles" goto :FindFiles

cd "C:\Users\Neha\Desktop\GB PRoducts\OCR\test"

:: Append newline to text files that are missing newline on last line
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('"%~f0" :FindFiles') do echo(>>"%%F"

:: Merge the text files and prefix each line with file name
findstr "^" *.txt >output.log

exit /b


:FindFiles
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Define LF to contain a newline character
set lf=^


:: The above 2 blank lines are critical - do not remove

:: List files that are missing newline on last line
findstr /vm "!lf!" *.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either

```
type *.txt>x.x 2>&1
```

(`type` writes the filenames to STDERR and the file content to STDOUT.  `>output.log 2>&1` writes STDOUT to the file and STDERR to the same destination.)

or

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do (echo %%a&type "%%a")
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan. I couldn't get the second option to work... but the first one worked like a charm!

Comment: if you try it on commandline (outside a batchfile), use `%a` instead of `%%a`. If it still doesn't work, I'd like to know, what exactly happens (it works for me)